# Which regular expression to use in order to determine which characters to escape for html attributes and javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, escaping, security

I am adopting some code from Twig (a php template framework) for escaping html and js output. Now I don't entirely understand the regex they are using.

For the full Twig code:

```
git clone git://github.com/fabpot/Twig.git
// the code is in Core.php in the function twig_escape_filter
```

They use:

```php
preg_replace_callback( '#[^a-zA-Z0-9,\._]#Su'   , '_twig_escape_js_callback'               , $string ); // for javascript
preg_replace_callback( '#[^a-zA-Z0-9,\.\-_]#Su' , '_twig_escape_html_attr_callback' , $string ); // for html attibutes
```

Where the callback functions will replace everything that corresponds to the negative character class.

As far as I can tell, this is equivalent (getting rid of some backslashes):

```php
'#[^a-zA-Z0-9,._]#Su'
'#[^a-zA-Z0-9,._-]#Su'
```

Now we see that for javascript they allow commas, which I don't understand because a comma is a control character in a javascript context. Take this example of a comma exploit:

```php
// say we have a function call to a javascript function like this
function ajax( timeout, onerror, onsuccess ) {...};

// now assume I get the timeout value from somewhere dodgy (in php)
$timeout = escapeJS( '1000, evilCallback, evilCallback2' );

echo "ajax( $timeout, myErrorHandler, mySuccessHandler );"
```

Note that javascript will happily ignore the extra parameters...

In the html attribute, the idea is to prevent closing the attribute, hence they don't allow spaces, since it is common to write attributes without quotes and in html4 it is legal as well. However, i see spaces used in attributes for giving multiple classes to an element like: `<tr class="tablerow odd">`. So dissallowing spaces prevents class attributes like this from coming from a database with templates or other sources...

1. Given that in xhtml it is forbidden to use attributes without quotes and my site generates xhtml strict doctype, can I afford to allow spaces?
2. Should I forbid the comma for javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `htmlspecialchars` for escaping HTML and `json_encode` for escaping Javascript.

```
$timeout = json_encode('1000, evilCallback, evilCallback2');
echo "ajax( $timeout, myErrorHandler, mySuccessHandler );";
```

Output:

```
ajax( "1000, evilCallback, evilCallback2", myErrorHandler, mySuccessHandler );
```

In your case you should also validate the actual content of the `$timeout` var, or cast it to int as this:

```
$timeout = json_encode((int)'1000, evilCallback, evilCallback2');
echo "ajax( $timeout, myErrorHandler, mySuccessHandler );";
```

Output:

```
ajax( 1000, myErrorHandler, mySuccessHandler );
```

The `json_encode` is not really needed when you cast to int, because PHP integers are also valid JS integers, but it is a good practice to escape all your data for the appropriate context nevertheless.

---

**Update:** Regarding the Twig code you're trying to adapt, it seems that it does not produce actual Javascript literals, but escapes strings for inclusion *into* Javascript literals — this is apparent from the actual use of `\xHH` escape codes, which in JS are valid only inside strings (and regular expressions, but that's beside the point). It should be used as this:

```
$timeout = escapeJS('1000, evilCallback, evilCallback2');
echo "ajax('$timeout', myErrorHandler, mySuccessHandler);";
```

Notice extra quotes around `$timeout` in the `echo`. This is likely done this way to allow composition of longer JS strings from multiple escaped parts, like `'foo $escaped_part1 bar $escaped_part2 baz'`.

Comment: I don't agree, http://blog.astrumfutura.com/2012/03/a-hitchhikers-guide-to-cross-site-scripting-xss-in-php-part-1-how-not-to-use-htmlspecialchars-for-output-escaping/

Comment: Have you bothered to actually read that article and understand its implications? My hunch is that those Twig regexen that you're trying to use have tons more implications than the humble problems with `htmlspecialchars`, most of which require you to actively try to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: Could you give an example? The link to the full code is in the question. Note that the author of that article proposes the Twig code as a good implementation. Other that that, yes I read it entirely, including the comments to understand the full implications. As far as I see the twig code is adhering more or less to the rules from: [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet), be it somewhat more lightweight than ESAPI which is not ready for production in PHP.

Comment: About shooting yourself in the foot, htmlspecialchar's need for explicitly setting encoding and flags already merits a wrapper function. The twig code are basically advanced wrapper functions.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` already defaults to UTF-8 encoding in PHP 5.4. You're going with running regex for _every_ bit of string that you'll use in HTML (keep in mind that regex is _not_ light on performance), just in order to fix a problem that has already been addressed. Wrapping `htmlspecialchars` just to provide a sane default encoding for legacy PHP installations is still going to be _much_ lighter than running tons of regex.

Comment: Lightness is not a worry. Security is. I cannot control the encoding of my enduser, but what I do know is that htmlspecialchars has limited encoding support. So you have to deal with that. Further 5.4 is all good and nice, but most stable versions of linux servers ship with 5.3, which will return an empty string on wrongly encoded characters, another issue to deal with. I think htmlspecialchars hasn't shown us the last of its quirks yet.

Comment: You _do_ control the encoding; if your script works all in UTF-8, and you declare UTF-8 encoding in your content-type, the user's browser will comply and work in UTF-8. You will only see wrongly-encoded characters if the remote user intentionally tampers and provides invalid data, in which case I believe it is reasonable that tampered data is to be disregarded completely. `htmlspecialchars` is not somehow "special" in the PHP universe; it is just another example of the unreliability of the whole language.

Comment: How can I control the content-type from a php library? First you tell me to use htmlspecialchars and now you tell me it is unreliable?

Comment: In your question you're talking about how "your site" generates XHTML, now it turns out we're talking about a reusable library, which quite much changes the scenario. `htmlspecialchars` is not unreliable, but it _does_ have gotchas, just like much of all the rest of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

What I found on [XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet):

For HTML attributes:

> Properly quoted attributes can only be escaped with the corresponding quote. Unquoted attributes can be broken out of with many characters, including [space] % * + , - / ; < = > ^ and |.

I suppose looking at it like that means that there is no way to get both protected against unquoted attributes and have spaces in your attributes. I suppose the escape function could add the quotes itself, but that would be inconsistent an create situations where vulues would be quoted twice, basically unquoting them... So, for now I have made two escaping functions, allowing the user to call one explicitely that allows the space, knowing that they must put quotes.

Considering javascript:

> Except for alphanumeric characters, escape all characters less than 256 with the \xHH format to prevent switching out of the data value into the script context or into another attribute. DO NOT use any escaping shortcuts like \" because the quote character may be matched by the HTML attribute parser which runs first. These escaping shortcuts are also susceptible to "escape-the-escape" attacks where the attacker sends \" and the vulnerable code turns that into \" which enables the quote.
>
> If an event handler is properly quoted, breaking out requires the corresponding quote. However, we have intentionally made this rule quite broad because event handler attributes are often left unquoted. Unquoted attributes can be broken out of with many characters including [space] % * + , - / ; < = > ^ and |. Also, a  closing tag will close a script block even though it is inside a quoted string because the HTML parser runs before the JavaScript parser.

This seems to indicate that we should escape everything. I have opted to keep underscore, since that can be part of javascript names and dot in order to allow inserting numerical values with a decimal point. I hope that leaves no vulnerabilities.

I suppose the Twig code has a bug leaving that comma around and [I will file a report](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/765) so they can look into it.